# Вывод измененного массива

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть задача,найти в массиве максимальный и минимальный елемент, и поменять местами. Я нашел такой пример, но **не знаю как вывести измененный массив:**

```
#include <iostream>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int a;
    int N;
    int b;
    int c;
    int k;
    int g;
    int arr[N];
    int max = arr[0];
    int min = arr[0];
    cout << "vvedit N=";
    cin >> N;
    cout << "vvedit massiv";

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (max < arr[i])
        {
            max = arr[i];
            k = i;
        }

        if (min > arr[i])
        {
            min = arr[i];
            g = i;
        }
    }

    a = max = k;
    b = min = g;
    c = a;
    a = b;
    b = c;
    cout << "max=" << max << endl;
    cout << "min=" << min << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i];
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

Comment: нет, не нашли и не поменяли

Comment: Нашел - да, поменял местами - нет

Comment: У вас в коде нет строк которые меняют два элемента местами, именно поэтому на экране вы вдидите "правильный" результат выполнения данного кода, а не желаемый результат.

Comment: @nick_n_a как "на экране" может быть "правильный" результат, если `min`/`max` инициализируются до ввода массива?

Comment: У вас в коде отсутствует присвоение, т.е. отсутствует строка `arr[???]=???` (??? - это правильное выражение) поэтому массив у вас остаётся без изменений. Вы не выполнили задачу - не поменяли их местами.

Comment: @Igor не согласен, тот кусок кода правильный. Ошибка в другом. Хотя... там `k` и `g` незадано - что приведёт ещё к одной  ошибке

Comment: @nick_n_a не-е-е-т, это я не согласен :). Что вообще такое `arr[N]` до ввода `N`?

Comment: @Igor Ну это уже третья ошибка:)

Comment: @nick_n_a нет, первая

Comment: @nick_n_a, `g` and  `k ` заданы, у них есть тип int,они нужны для замены елементов местами, через буферную переменную.

Comment: @Igor `arr[N];`, ето массив длины N

Comment: @AwesomeMan дело в том, что если min или max перепадёт в нулевую позицию, то g и k у вас останутся без изменений, и будут иметь произвольное значение - т.е. программа ваша или даст плохой результат "случайное число" или повиснет. И так, у вас 3 ошибки. 1. N задана позже чем arr[N]. 2. не задано g, k 3. Не присвоено `arr[]` не сделан обмен

Comment: @AwesomeMan - в строчке `int arr[N];` `N` еще неизвестно

Comment: @Igor, ето его,тип. ен,вводится потом, да и вообще какая разница?

Comment: Разница проявится когда memory fault или exception выдаст :) А возможно табличку "ваша программа выполнила недопустимую функцию и будет закрыта"

Comment: @nick_n_a,можете написать как правильно?, я не знаю как написать иначе

Comment: Вас послушать - любой кусок кода - правильный) Просто он, возможно, делает не то, что от него ожидают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ой, что-то вы недоговариваете :)

Ну как *вот это* вообще может скомпилироваться, да еще и работать - не понимаю:

```
int N;
int arr[N];
int max = arr[0];
```

Вот, держите:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    unsigned int N;
    cout << "Number of items: ";
    cin >> N;
    vector<int> a(N);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        cout << "a["<<i<<"] = ";
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    int min, max;
    size_t imin, imax;
    min = max = a[imin = imax = 0];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        if (a[i] > max)
        {
            imax = i;
            max = a[i];
        }
        else if (a[i] < min)
        {
            imin = i;
            min = a[i];
        }
    }
    int tmp = a[imax];
    a[imax] = a[imin];
    a[imin] = tmp;

    cout << "max = " << max << endl;
    cout << "min = " << min << endl;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        cout << "a["<<i<<"] = " << a[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Если **позарез** надо через массивы, замените

```
vector<int> a(N);
```

на

```
int * a = new int[N];
```

и перед выходом из `main` добавьте `delete[] a;`.